# Not able to connect to Hipchat with errbot ? getting permission denied for socket .

Tags: bots, hipchat, errbot

While connect error bot with self hosted . Getting this error while doing it -

```
10:40:34 DEBUG    sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlst RECV: <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls" />
10:40:34 DEBUG    sleekxmpp.features.featur Starting TLS
10:40:34 INFO     sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlst Negotiating TLS
10:40:34 INFO     sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlst Using SSL version: TLSv1
10:40:34 DEBUG    sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlst Event triggered: socket_error
10:40:34 ERROR    sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlst **Socket Error #13: Permission denied**
10:40:34 DEBUG    sleekxmpp.xmlstream.xmlst reconnecting...
```

This is config which i am using for same .

```
BACKEND = 'Hipchat'  # Errbot will start in text mode (console only mode) and will answer commands from there.

BOT_DATA_DIR = r'/Users/XXX/errbot/errbot/data'
BOT_EXTRA_PLUGIN_DIR = '/Users/XXXX/errbot/errbot/plugins'

BOT_LOG_FILE = r'/Users/XXXX/errbot/errbot/errbot.log'
BOT_LOG_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG

BOT_ADMINS = ('@XXXXX', )  # !! Don't leave that to "CHANGE ME" if you connect your errbot to a chat system !!

# The identity, or credentials, used to connect to a server
BOT_IDENTITY = {
    'username': 'XXXX',  # The JID of the user you have created for the bot
    'password': 'XXXXX',       # The corresponding password for this user
    'token': 'XXXXXX',
    'endpoint' : 'https://xxxx.xxxx.com',
}
```

Can someone please let me know what i am doing wrong in above config ?

Or please also suggest any other bot (in python) that works with self hosted Hipchat .

Answer (score 0):

Hipchat Server removed external access to the XMPP ports on the 2.0.7  release, in favor of supporting only communication over port 443 (using XMPP's BOSH protocol).

Depending on your server version, you might be able to enable them back by running `hipchat network --enable-xmpp-ports`.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/hipchatkb/external-xmpp-ports-5222-5223-disabled-by-default-in-hipchat-server-2-0-7-859442760.html has more information on this topic.